# Spring security and keyclock - ServerHttpSecurity error

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to add Spring Security to my Spring Boot application. I've created new SecurityConfig class and I've added the code below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain configSecurity(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
            .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange.matchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).permitAll().anyExchange().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(ServerHttpSecurity.OAuth2ResourceServerSpec::jwt)
            .build();
    }
```

}

When I try to start the application I get the error:

> 2021-04-08 08:58:47.828  INFO 3040 --- [           main]
> o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request
> with
> [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6089c1e3,
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4bba628,
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@47b4fcd5,
> org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@439acac0,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6af447b6,
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@5679e464,
> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4420f4d4,
> org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@517594dd,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@67231d8d,
> org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@59b5251d,
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7d6b0636,
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4b50ebea]
>
> 2021-04-08 08:58:47.883  WARN 3040 --- [           main]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'configSecurity' defined in class path
> resource [it/config/SecurityConfig.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'configSecurity'
> parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

And:

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description: Parameter 0 of method configSecurity in
> it.config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity'
> that could not be found.
>
> Action: Consider defining a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity' in
> your configuration.

Do you know how to solve?

Below my dependecy:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You need to enable @EnableWebFluxSecurity to use ServerHttpSecurity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved using `HttpSecurity` instead of `ServerHttpSecurity`. Below my new code:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()).oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
   }
}
```

Comment: why does this solve it?

Comment: That solution works but uses the deprecated class

Answer (score 1):

Try annotating the class that bean is in with the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
```

Also, make sure that bean is public - see if all of those fix it? If not - could you provide a Full Stack-Trace of the exception.

Thanks, Ben

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering but the error is the same. I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

try adding all of these annotations at the top.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
```

Sometimes the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` helps

Comment: ServerHttpSecurity is only available for spring webflux:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/web/server/ServerHttpSecurity.html

Comment: Oh - sorry I edited it didn't know you are using WebFlux - look at the previous version that might do it

Answer (score 0):

For future readers.

This "stopped the exception" for me.

Below (java code) gives me the exception.

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity' in your configuration. "ServerHttpSecurity"

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
            // implementation not shown
    }
```

I changed the "signature" to this: (below java code)

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
             //implementation not shown
    }
```

When I wrote this answer, my versions were at:

```
  +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:3.0.6
       |    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.0.8
```

I "found" the new code at:

```
https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/
```

The below code is a copy and paste from the spring.io website, in case the page dies or the content changes in the future.  I did not write or test or anything the code below that I took from the spring.io page above.

```
package com.example.securingweb;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin((form) -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            )
            .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
             User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

and below is some of "my code"..with some alternate syntax sugars

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.EndpointRequest;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfiguration {



    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {



/* below is "allow anything/everything".  start here to make sure your REST endpoint is working...THEN start adding restrictions (and get rid of this allow-anything-everything code) */
//        http
//                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
//                        .anyRequest().permitAll());


// below sugar syntax works
//                http
//                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
//                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
//                        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("info", "health"))
//                        .permitAll()
//                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
//                );


        // (OR) below sugar syntax works
//        http
//                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
//                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
//                        .requestMatchers("/anotherpathforanexample/**", "/actuator/**").permitAll()
//                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
//                );


// (OR) below sugar syntax works
                http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint.class)).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated());

    
        return http.build();


    }

}
```